# Facebook API - getting events from restricted pages

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I want to make **an events calendar** using `Facebook API`. I have an array with page URLs I want to scan and take its events. The problem is, I am using an `App Access Token` and I can't obtain events from pages with `restricted age` (alcohol pages etc.). Is there any way I can obtain those events?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access restricted Pages with an App Token. You have to use a User Token of a User who can access the Page, or a Page Token of that Page. There is no other way, or the restriction would be pointless.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the advanced settings of your applications page on developers.facebook.com. e.g. for me it would be https://developers.facebook.com/apps//settings/advanced/. And set app restrictions for 'references alchohol' to yes, similar for age.

[Screenshot of setting attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw70v.png)

Comment: that is for the app only, it obviously does not affect the pages you want to access...that would be weird.